# Formatting numpy array until it gets to needed length Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, append

How can I write a code where it completes the array `a` by appending `append_val` until the `length` of the array is reached. So the length of `a` is 6 and the expected length is 10 so it will append `append_val` until the desired length `10` in this case is reached. How would I be able to do a numpy function that would get me the Expected Output.

```
import numpy as np 

length = 10
append_val = 0 
a = np.array([12,34,1,3,12,34])
```

Expected output:

```
[12,34,1,3,12,34,0,0,0,0]
```

Comment: What have yo tried?  Have you read the docs of functions like `np.concatenate` or `hp.hstack`?  Keep in mind that lists are designed to grow/append.  Arrays don't "grow", rather you just make a new array from several pieces.

Comment: Did you try putting, for example, `numpy pad array` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=numpy+pad+array)? Or [`numpy resize array`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=numpy+resize+array)? Or anything at all along those lines? Even [copying and pasting your question title](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Formatting+numpy+array+until+it+gets+to+needed+length+Python) should get you *somewhere* with a bit of digging. On Stack Overflow, [you are expected to make some attempt to solve the problem yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([12,34,1,3,12,34])
a.resize(10)
print(a)
```

Comment: This is a rare case where `resize` method actually is useful.

Answer (score 0):

If `append_val` is constant, you could use

```
a = np.pad(a, (0, length-len(a)), "constant", constant_values=append_val)
```